# WPF - Load image from file in user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to load an image from file within a WPF user control. I was able to load the image when the image control was on the main window, but now I've moved it into it's own user control it won't load.

My current attempt

> this.image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new
>   Uri(@"‪C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\R0010568.JPG"));

When i run it, I get the below error.

> System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.'

I've also tried adding `file://` at the start of the URI, and got the same result.

I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious, but googling hasn't helped this time.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `new Uri("‪C:/Users/Jon/Desktop/R0010568.JPG")` should work.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, as I said. The above code isn't working. I was looking for help determining why.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the issue. I copied the path from windows, and seems like it added a character somewhere (that wasn't visible in visual studio), typed the path in and it worked. Thanks for your help, apologies for my angry comment above. :)